# Iterator/Range design, can a lightweight input iterator implemented with C++/java's iterator model?

Tags: design, c++, iterator

I'd like to better understand Iterator/Range design decisions (focusing on InputIterators).

Basically, this is the java model:

```
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Object o = iter.next();
    // do something with o
}
```

But, here is a [quote](https://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/790785-iterators-java-c) from James Kanze:

> Not that Java's iterators are perfect, either. The merge access and
>   incrementing---as did the USL iterators. By the time Java was being
>   developed, we'd already established that this wasn't a good idea, so
>   it's hard to understand why they did it.

He says that merging access and incrementing is not a good idea. I was trying to find out the "why", but haven't found anything.

The "fixed" iterator look like this (which is the GoF iterator):

```
while (!iter.isDone()) {
    Object o = iter.element();
    // do something with o
    iter.next();
}
```

For C++1z, we could have the new range model. For InputRange, `end()` could return a special sentinel type, so handling end-of-stream condition can be optimized well.

Now, suppose that I want to create an InputRange (which is a lightweight range: doesn't store the read element), which read lines from a file/socket. Here, end-of-stream condition is only discovered after trying reading. An "optimal" iterator model could be this:

```
string line;
while (iter.getNext(line)) {  // getNext returns false at end-of-stream
    // do something with line
}
```

This iterator differs from any of the previous ones.

My questions are:

- what are the cons of Java's access+increment iterator model (can you give an example of that)?
- can my desired lightweight iterator be implemented with any of the mentioned iterator-types (java/GoF/C++)? If not, then what are the pros of the other iterator models, so not my "optimal" iterator model is used instead? Or in other words, what can be the cons of my "optimal" iterator model, so it is not generally used?

Comment: I read the thread you referenced and could not understand the logic James Kanze entirely. While it is true you cannot access the first element without iterating once, an empty stream has no first element. To determine this, without knowing the length of the stream (a fundamental property of streams, especially for infinite streams), you must perform some operation prior to accessing the initial element.

Comment: Design decisions are not always perfect (for some definition of "perfect," including yours).  Your iterator can probably be trivially implemented by writing your own method that combines the `hasNext()` and `next()` methods.  Go for it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: yes, but that iterator won't be lightweight, as it uses a (supposedly) non-lightweight iterator. I'm not saying that my "optimal" iterator is perfect. I'd like to know the pros/cons of each iterator approach. But currently, I don't see what drawbacks "my" approach have (I'm sure it is not "my" approach. Surely, it has been invented a lot of times before, but java/c++ doesn't use this model for some reason.)

Answer (score 4):

> what are the cons of Java's access+increment iterator model (can you give an example of that)?

Well, there is the obvious: the fact that you cannot increment *without* accessing.

Let's say that you have an iterator over an array. And you want to skip the first 5 elements. That requires accessing those elements, even though you just want to skip them. That's 5 extra dereferences, when all you needed was to increment a pointer 5 times.

Or increment a pointer by 5 once.

> can my desired lightweight iterator be implemented with any of the mentioned iterator-types (java/GoF/C++)?

It can be implemented in C++, but only in the sense that you can either add that function to your iterator type or that you can create a helper function that takes an InputIterator and performs that operation on it.

You cannot *force* someone to use your InputIterators in this fashion. The C++ standard has defined the InputIterator concept, and that's what standard library features use.

> If not, then what are the pros of the other iterator models, so not my "optimal" iterator model is used instead?

The C++ iterator model analogizes iterators with pointers: a specific location in a sequence of things. A pointer knows how to get to the next iterator, and it knows how to get what it points to.

But it doesn't know whether the next iterator points to a legitimate object. A pointer can increment, but it lacks knowledge about whether the next pointer is valid.

This is why C++ uses iterator pairs; the end iterator tells you where to stop.

Having an iterator that knows when to stop requires that the iterator also contain the information to know when to stop. Oh sure, for a file-based InputIterator, you already have that. But what about inputting from a string you already have?

Consider `std::copy_n`. It performs `n` copies/increments from the input iterator to the output iterator. But it never checks whether the input iterator actually has another value; you are expected to provide an iterator that has at least `n` items in it. If you don't, you get UB.

With your kind of iterator, you get `n` copies, but also `n` checks against the terminating condition. And again, for a file-based character InputIterator, you'd have to do that anyway. But for other kinds of iterators, it's pointless additional work.

C++ likes the idea that you don't pay for what you don't use. And if you don't need an end point for an iterator, you shouldn't have that as part of your iterator model.

> Or in other words, what can be the cons of my "optimal" iterator model, so it is not generally used?

The fact that, as a model, it is not optimal. It may be optimal in a specific case, but it requires overhead that the C++ InputIterator concept does not require.

Also, there's the fact that the `value_type` being iterated over is required to be Assignable in some fashion (since `getNext` must assign the new value to it).  Which also means that the `getNext` function copy/moves into the object.

Furthermore, the type must also have a default constructor or an otherwise "empty" state, since you must construct it *before* reading data into it.

The C++ iterator model imposes no such requirements on `value_type`.

---

From the comments:

> If you add the read object into the iterator, it can be much more heavyweight. For example, if you read lines, then it will contain a string (allocation happen, etc.). For "my" iterator, it doesn't have to.

And yet, both still carry the burden of having that `string` around. In your model, the caller has to provide the `string`. In the STL iterator/range model, the iterator/range provides it. So while you could say that an STL iterator/range is more expensive, it is an expect that somebody is going to have to pay either way.

So neither is more efficient than the other. By having the iterator/range model pay that cost, it allows such objects to work *without* external state.

Comment: For `std::copy_n`, `getNext`'s return value can be ignored. And if getNext is inlined, its return value calculation can be optimized away. so it doesn't matter too much. For the `value_type` comment, getNext() could return a pair: a bool and a return value. My question is a more of a conceptual question. Java has a separate `hasNext()`, `next()` function, C++ has two-iterators model, both of them incapable doing (if I'm not mistaken) one of the simplest iteration: reading line from a file the most simplest way. "My" version can do it, and so I still don't see any drawbacks of this method.

Comment: "my" version has this drawback too: "the fact that you cannot increment without accessing.". If this is important, then a `bool skip()` method can be added.

Comment: Basically, the intent of my question was that I'd like to design an iterator which is the "best" available, that's why I'm trying to collect all pros/cons of each method.

Comment: @geza: "*For std::copy_n, getNext's return value can be ignored.*" But it still has to be *generated*. And therefore, the test has to be done. "*I'd like to design an iterator which is the "best" available*" "best" is in the eye of the beholder. I don't see your example as being any better objectively than standard iterators, and it is worse for many use cases, as outlined. A simpler way to read lines from a file is `for(const auto &line : line_reader(stream))`. Where `line_reader` extracts a range of lines. It works fine with the Iterator model.

Comment: Yes, but that's why I said that if it is inlined, then it will be optimized away. If it is not inline, then it doesn't matter too much anyway. But, if it matters, then we can add this functionality too in the iterator: `getForcedNext()`, or something like that. There has to be a reason that every language has its own differing iterators, C++ will be (hopefully) extended with ranges, etc. I do think that there exist a "best", or almost the "best" iterator... Besides, "my" iterator can be used to implement C++'s InputRange (so it can be used conveniently), but the converse is not true.

Comment: @geza: "*Besides, "my" iterator can be used to implement C++'s InputRange (so it can be used conveniently), but the converse is not true.*" Nonsense. You can implement your thing API on top of an iterator pair. See, your problem is that your concept doesn't implement "iterators"; it implements *iteration*. There's a difference, and I pointed that out in my post. "Iteration" requires knowledge of where it terminates; "iterators" do not. It's the lower-level construct.

Comment: How can you implement it "lightweightly"? As I see, `begin()` needs to read an element, so it can be compared to `end()`. So it needs to store the read element into the iterator.

Comment: @geza: You never said "lightweightly". Also, it's only "lightweight" by comparison for iteration over things that don't have an end-point. As I pointed out in my post, for iteration over a "begin/end" pairs, your equivalent (which is functionally just a range) will be heavier weight than regular iterators if you don't need the "end". That's why iterator is the base type and ranges are built on top of them. It is lighter-weight.

Comment: @geza: Basically, you're optimizing your system for the case of Iterator/DefaultConstructibleSentinel.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't mentioned it in my comments here, but I mentioned it in the question. If you add the read object into the iterator, it can be much more heavyweight. For example, if you read lines, then it will contain a string (allocation happen, etc.). For "my" iterator, it doesn't have to. Yes, I'm optimizing it for this case, because for the other cases, it will be almost as optimal than the current 2-iterator solution. The 2-iterator solution usually more heavyweight (or equal) then the range one (because you have to store container info for both of the iterators).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65676/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-geza).